# Android native library dependency not found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my Android Studio project I use a third-party library (which I cannot edit) which requires several native libraries. When I access this third-party library in my app, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load avutil-52 from 
loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
[dexPath=/data/app/com.myApp.debug.apk, 
libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.myApp.debug]: 
findLibrary returned null
```

I use Android Studio 1.2.2, so Gradle supports using a jniLibs folder. My Gradle build file specifies the jniLibs folder, for safety:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/src'
            }
            jniLibs {
                srcDirs 'src/main/jniLibs'
            }
        }
    }
```

}

And here I have my libraries:

```
src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/*.so
```

The folder includes some other libraries, which are working in the app, so I know the folder is being included.

When I inspect the generated APK, all the *.so files are included in the libs folder. However, when I check the installed app, I only find three of the expected six libraries:

```
adb shell ls /data/app-lib/com.myApp

first.so
second.so
third.so
```

I've also checked the `/data/data/com/myApp.debug/app_lib/` folder, and none of the other three dependencies are there.

Not being a native Android developer, I find this very puzzling. What could be causing some dependencies to be included, and others to be excluded? Is there a way of forcing Android to recognise the three missing files, and making sure they're installed? Without having to edit the third party library which uses them, of course.

**EDIT 1:**

Could this code from the third-party library be causing a problem?

```
public StartFunction() {
    String arch = System.getProperty("os.arch");
    this.ARM = arch.toUpperCase().contains("ARM") || arch.toUpperCase().contains("AARCH64");
    if(this.ARM) {
        this.LoadLibraries();
    }
}

private void LoadLibraries() {
    System.loadLibrary("first");
    System.loadLibrary("second");
    System.loadLibrary("third");
    System.loadLibrary("fourth");
    System.loadLibrary("fifth");
    System.loadLibrary("sixth");
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

This is the full exception from logcat. Package names slightly changed to protect the guilty.

```
  06-30 09:19:08.505  15069-15069/com.myApp.debug E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.myApp.debug, PID: 15069
      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load avutil-52 from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.myApp.debug-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.myApp.debug-1]: findLibrary returned null
              at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
              at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
              at com.thirdPartyApp.embedded.Call.LoadLibraries(Call.java:289)
              at com.thirdPartyApp.embedded.Call.<init>(Call.java:214)
              at com.thirdPartyApp.embedded.thirdPartyCall$29.run(thirdParty.java:963)
              at com.thirdPartyApp.embedded.DownloadFile.onPostExecute(DownloadFile.java:56)
              at com.thirdPartyApp.embedded.DownloadFile.onPostExecute(DownloadFile.java:16)
              at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
              at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
              at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT 3:**

I've managed to get this working, but in a kind of dirty way. I don't know exactly why this happened, but I do know what happened:

I had all six the compiled libraries needed by the third party SDK I'm using placed in `src/main/jniLibs/armeabi`. Conventional wisdom dictates that this should work for all ARM devices. However, when installing the app on an ARM device only three of the six libraries were installed.

Dirty solution: place all six libraries in the `src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a` folder as well. This scattershot approach meant that all six libraries are installed, and available.

I'll update this once we figure out why this happened.

Comment: Have you tried to add your third-party library as a module? 
I think it will solve your problem. By the way, if you have the maven/bintree file path you can add those third-party as a dependencies.

Let me know if it solved your case.

Comment: I tried the module route, but no luck. I had exactly the same results, the first dependency it tries to load could not be found.

Comment: Can you add the full logcat exception?

Comment: Added an edit to my original question.

Comment: [lib]avutil-52 is a library from FFmpeg project. On Android every library loaded usually starts with "lib", therefore it is strange that the it tries to load "avutil-52" and not "libavutil-52.so" (lib prefix and .so postfix are automatically added by System.loadLibrary).

Comment: avutil-52 looks like a Windows DLL...how it got into armeabi arch surprises me. Instead libavutil-52 is the right one.

Comment: The file itself is indeed called libavutil-52.so, but apparently the reference to avutil-52 works as well. In various implementations of the FFmpeg libraries, I've seen people use both together.

Comment: If the libraries are there in the apk but don't get unpacked to the lib folder on install, then that's a problem; you've obfuscated too much of the information here to work out what's wrong, though. Can you include the exact full pathnames of the libraries inside the APK? (e.g. "lib/armeabi-v7a/libwhatevers.so") That would probably help figure out why the package installer isn't unpacking them. Also, what android version are you running on?

Comment: Edited to reflect a work-around I've implemented.